# php Sentry: Force user to logout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cartalyst-sentry

I want to automatically logout inactive users.
Problem is that users are still logged when I mark them as inactive.

I think that problem is that session variable for each inactive user are still valid and they can easily login even if I mark them as they are not online.

Does someone knows where's the problem ?

```
DB::table ( 'users' )->where ( 'username', $user->username )->update ( array (
                                'online' => 0,
                                'kicked' => '' 
                        ) );
```

Comment: Are you using CRON to perodically check fo inactive users or what ? The information about user being logged in is stored in client session/cookie so I don't see any way to actually log user out without client making the request by himself. You could write some Javascript which would periodically check if user is not online and eventually log him out then and even redirect to homepage or something. But it all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MaksymCierzniak yes, I am using laravel built in CRON and I compare user activity (I added new column to users table that updates on each route). I "created" patch for my problem.

If user is inactive (using JavaScript to detect it) I kick him (log him out with kicked time)